# How do I display a countdown timer for 45 seconds on a JPanel. How would I do this?

Tags: java

I want to create a 45 second timer to display on a JPanel. The time should be displayed on the JPanel so it is visible to the user. It's part of a game I am creating.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You probably already tried something, would be nice to show it. We can begin working from there. And also, try explaining where you're stuck..

Comment: Cool. My timer is on a specific JPanel. Everytime I go that JPanel, I want the timer to reset. Is there a method for this?